# How to print Serial port incomming data to lable

Tags: c#

```
    private void cliButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp = new SerialPort();
        sp.PortName = "COM14";
        sp.BaudRate = 19200;
        sp.Parity = Parity.None;
        sp.DataBits = 8;
        sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        sp.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
        sp.DtrEnable = true;
        sp.RtsEnable = true;

        sp.Open();

        if (!sp.IsOpen)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Serial port is not opened");
            return;
        }
        sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
        sp.WriteLine("AT+CLIP=1" + Environment.NewLine);
        byte [] data= new byte [sp.BytesToRead];
        sp.Read(data, 0, data.Length);


    }
```

Here is my code.
it is use to communicate with the mobile phone through serial port.
Here im sending AT command (AT+CLIP=1 this command use to take CLI of the incomming call) to serialport. Then i read the data of the serial port. My problem is How can i print this readed data in the label.

Answer (score 1):

BytesToRead is going to be 0 when you run this code without a debugger.  It takes time for the serial port device to send a response.  This ought to solve your problem:

```
label1.Text = sp.ReadLine();
```

ReadLine() keeps reading until it detects a SerialPort.NewLine in the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the result that is returned you can do:

label.Text = sp.ReadExisting();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display port output in hex format separated by space use this:

```
_label.Text = string.Join(" ", data.Select(b => string.Format("{0:X2}", b)));
```